# Unknown authentication strategy "local", nodejs-mysql

Tags: mysql, angularjs, node.js, passport.js

I am working on Angular-node-mysql application. I am trying to implement login functionality using passport.js. I am getting error "unknown authentication strategy "local". I checked the other posts online, but failed to fixed the issue. I used the reference :
[Github reference](https://gist.github.com/manjeshpv/84446e6aa5b3689e8b84)
[image]

my code : server.js[image]
[image]

[image]

Error I see on browser: [image]

I am unable to figure out my mistake

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You named your strategy 'local-login'.  Try changing

```
app.post("/login", passport.authenticate('local') .....
```

to

```
app.post("/login", passport.authenticate('local-login') .....
```